# Is "sono già venuto qui prima" an usual sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Is "sono già venuto qui prima" a correct/usual way to say that I have already been here before in Italian, similar to "sono già stato qui prima"? I ask because the corresponding former sentence in Portuguese (a similar language) is usual, but I'm not sure the same applies to Italian. [DeepL Translator](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) has translated it to the latter. There is also a similar [Duolingo sentence](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/557750) in the Italian course, but unfortunately sometimes its content is not idiomatic, so I'd like the opinion of native speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both *sono già venuto qui* and *sono già stato qui* are normal, idiomatic sentences. The variants with *prima*, however, are less so: they sound like translations from English (which, if I understand correctly, they are).

More colloquial versions would be *qui ci sono già stato/venuto* or *ci sono già stato/venuto, qui*.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I agree the phrase in itself is grammatically correct but as a native speaker I wouldn't use the word *prima* at all. The most common expression in spoken language is "Sono già stato\a qui" using the verb stare instead of venire.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo intervento!